# Auto run javascript code on page load

Tags: javascript

How can I run javascript code just after page load, when page is loaded, it trigger, and when I go to another page it also trigger another piece of code for that page, how can I do it ?

Comment: `window.onload = function() {
  // do something
}`

Comment: read up jquery `$(document).ready()`

Comment: @Aditya that is jquery.

Comment: this is such a simple web search `javascript page load`. Please show some efort before posting rudimantary questions here

Comment: yeah I mentioned that in the comment. @Mr_Green

Comment: I mean why he will use jquery to load a page? isn't that overkill? @Aditya

Comment: @Mr_Green I thought he was asking how to execute a javascript code on page load and not load a page using javascript. And using jquery was just a suggestion for that.

Answer (score 5):

You can try

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function codeAddress() {
            alert('ok');
        }
        window.onload = codeAddress;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Click here http://jsfiddle.net/NEfR2/

Answer (score 0):

`document.ready()` is a jQuery event. JQuery’s `document.ready()` method gets called as soon as the DOM is ready (which means that the browser has parsed the HTML and built the DOM tree). This allows you to run code as soon as the document is ready to be manipulated.

For example, if a browser supports the DOMContentLoaded event (as many non-IE browsers do), then it will fire on that event. However, IE can’t safely fire until the document’s readyState reaches “complete”, which is typically later.

You can find more info [here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) (of course, this requires jQuery to be loaded)

Comment: Ready is not a method of document - it is as you pointed  out - a function of the jQuery library which accepts the document as an parameter. $(function() {   // Handler for .ready() called. }); does exactly the same.